# replace %20 with hyphen in htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The following code to replace %20 with hyphen is not working perfectly. Some times it works and sometimes it doesn't and if there is a numeric in the title, the spaces are not replaced after the numeric. Any help?
For eg.
he is 30 years old
he-is-30%20years%20old

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (\s|%20)
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+([^\s%20]+)((?:\s|%20)+.*)$ $1-$2$3 [N,DPI]
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301,DPI]
```

Comment: The `RewriteRule` pattern matches against the %-decoded URL-path, so your _pattern_ seems to be unnecessarily complex - do you really need to match a literal `%20` (ie. a _doubly_ encoded space) in the URL?

Comment: sometimes the url title spaces are replaced with hyphens and sometimes its not..it simply shows %20 in the spaces as if the htaccess is not working.

Comment: secondly if the title has numeric value the hyphens are not replaced after the numerics

For eg
title =he is 30 yrs old
the code shows=he-is-30%20yrs%old

Comment: do you need the website URL??

Comment: "if the title has numeric value the hyphens are not replaced" - that was probably because of your `[^\s%20]` character class - this would have resulted in the pattern failing to match the `0` in `30 yrs old`, so the URL would not have been rewritten (hence you see the encoded space ie. `%20`). (You keep making references to "the title" - this doesn't sound right? The _title_ should already have been corrected/preprocessed long before trying to rewrite it in .htaccess?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of those complex replacements try these 2 rules to replace all space by hyphens:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule "^(\S*)\s+(\S*)$" /$1-$2 [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteRule "^(\S*)\s+(\S*\s+.*)$" $1-$2 [L]

# remove multiple hyphens
RewriteRule ^(.*)-{2,}(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=302]
```

Comment: Suppose if the title in the URL is "One from a Billion - Karting Challenge"

Comment: it might result  like /One-from-a-Billion---Karting-Challenge

Comment: it has to be 'One-from-a-Billion-Karting-Challenge'

Comment: we have to remove the hyphen occurring before and after a hyphen